# Why won't my function result print in my HtML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have scoured similar issues and tried a few different approaches, but the list generated by my JavaScript function will not show up in my HTML after running. One error that seems to keep showing up is: `document.getElementByID(...)` is null. Here is my code:

**HTML**:

```
      <input type="button" value="Natural Supports List" onclick="naturalSupports();"/>
    <p id="output"></p>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
document.getElementById("Natural Supports List").onclick = function naturalSupports (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var output = document.getElementById("output").value;
  output.innerHTML(userMessage);

}
  function naturalSupports(){

    var supports = [];
    var userSupports = "";
    var supportsloop = true;
    var totalSupports = 0;
    var userMessage = "";

    while (supportsloop) {
      userSupports = prompt("Enter one of your natural supports, or leave blank to stop.");
      if (userSupports === ""){
        supportsloop = false;
      }else{
        supports.push(userSupports); 
      }
    }

    totalSupports = supports.length;
    var userList;

    for(var index=0; index < supports.length; index++) {
      userList = supports[index] + "<br>";
    }


    listMessage = "Here is a list of your supports: ";
    userMessage = "<strong>Here is a list of your supports: </strong><br>" + userList;

    return userMessage;        
  }
```

Comment: Well one thing is `.getElementById("Natural Supports List")` doesn't make sense because you have no element with a matching id (so that'll return `null`). Another thing is that you should remove the `.value` part from `document.getElementById("output").value`, because (a) paragraph elements don't have a `.value`, and (b) you want a reference to the element itself so that you can say `output.innerHTML` on the next line. A third thing is the only place that calls `naturalSupports()` doesn't do anything with the return value, so obviously that value won't appear in the document...

Comment: `document.getElementById("Natural Supports List")` is undefined. But, that's just one of many bad practices.

Comment: "Natural Supports List" an  element with this id attribute is missing, and also there should not be space in an id attribute

Comment: Is your JS in your code AFTER your HTML where you have the `onclick`?

Comment: Also ```innerHTML``` is not a function, instead you want ```innerHTML = ..etc```

Comment: @jonmrich: yes it is. 

Thank you to everyone else too! I am new (I'm sure that is painfully obvious at this point) at this and feeling a bit lost.

Comment: The code for your function (the javascript) needs to before the HTML with the `onclick` in your code otherwise the function (naturalSupports) will never be found.

Comment: Here are the changes I have made. It keeps giving me an error of: e is undefined

HTML:

      <input id= "List" type="button" value="Natural Supports List" onclick="naturalSupports();"/>
    <p id="output"></p>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

JS:

document.getElementById("List").onclick = function naturalSupports (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  naturalSupports();
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  output.innerHTML(userMessage);
  
}

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call a function from Button onClick Action,
So change the Javascript code as following

```
function naturalSupports(){

    var supports = [];
    var userSupports = "";
    var supportsloop = true;
    var totalSupports = 0;
    var userMessage = "";

    while (supportsloop) {
      userSupports = prompt("Enter one of your natural supports, or leave blank to stop.");
      if (userSupports === ""){
        supportsloop = false;
      }else{
        supports.push(userSupports); 
      }
    }

    totalSupports = supports.length;
    var userList;

    for(var index=0; index < supports.length; index++) {
      userList = supports[index] + "<br>";
    }


    listMessage = "Here is a list of your supports: ";
    userMessage = "<strong>Here is a list of your supports: </strong><br>" + userList;

  var output = document.getElementById("output").value;
  output.innerHTML(userMessage);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code:- 
**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="Natural Supports List" id="natural" onclick="naturalSupports();"/>
    <p id="output"></p>
```

**Java Script**

```
  function naturalSupports(){

    var supports = [];
    var userSupports = "";
    var userList = "";
    var supportsloop = true;
    var totalSupports = 0;
    var userMessage = "";

    while (supportsloop) {
      userSupports = prompt("Enter one of your natural supports, or leave blank to stop.","");
      if (userSupports === ""){
        supportsloop = false;
      }else{
        supports.push(userSupports); 
      }
    }

    totalSupports = supports.length;
    var userList;

    for(var index=0; index < supports.length; index++) {
      userList += supports[index] + "<br>";
    }


    listMessage = "Here is a list of your supports: ";
    userMessage += "<strong>Here is a list of your supports: </strong><br>" + userList;

   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += userMessage;
  }
```

It is running perfectly.

Comment: I. COULD. KISS. YOU.
Seriously. Thank you so much!
While I am on here, if anyone has suggestions where I could go to be better at coding I would really appreciate it! I have winter break coming up and I want to really work at it - I know I still have a lot to learn!

Comment: You can learn a lot from online. Try to learn with your heart and mind. :P 
Concentration is very important :). 
Good luck

Comment: I have the soloLearn apps on my phone and I have tried Code Academy before too. 
Thank you for the suggestions.
Concentration is a difficult thing for me - my house is always chaotic. I will work on building a panic/coding room! :)

Answer (score -1):

Does your button have any id?
 "Natural Supports List" is your button's value.
So you can't use `document.getElementsById` to get the element.
Add an `id` attribute to your button. The function will run.

By the way, you'd better named `id` use a word without spaces.